# Could not get any response from server

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, client, instance, postman

I can´t connect to my server which I built at the AWS instance using the client code I wrote in Postman. My server is running. I can send messages from my postman app to my friend´s server in another instance. Also they can send me messages from their client code to my server.It´s just I can´t connect to my instance. Where could be the problem? Again, my server is running fine and answers to other requests.

This is the client side code in Postman. What could be the problem here? Thank you!

---

[image]

---

Comment: Please review the troubleshooting page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: You say you "can't connect" -- from where? And what, specifically, is the error?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The above code works fine when I try to send the message to my friend´s server in his instance. When I try to send it to my server in my instance it´s not working. I could see server is running without any problem and it print out messages from other postman client requests made from my friends computers. When I try from my postman app It says can´t get any response. I turned off firewall still didn´t work.